# How to activate Angular component only one time?

Tags: angular

I have main application component that contains tabs:

```html
    <tabs>
       <tab><app-layers *ngIf="tab === 'layers'"></app-layers></tab>
    </tabs>
```

The problem is when I switch between tabs it destroy and initialize the component again, how to initialize the component only one time then don't?

I know it can be solved using routing, but I have another structure of components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide your component and show it instead of destroying it and initializing it each time with `*ngIf`

```html
<tabs>
   <tab><app-layers [class.is-hidden]="tab !== 'layers'"></app-layers></tab>
</tabs>
```

```css
.is-hidden {
      display: none;
 }
```

**EDIT:**

you can use  a combination of `*ngIf` and `[class.is-hidden]` to achieve what you mentioned in the comments:

**how it works:**

First, you want to keep track of the tabs that are loaded, that why we use a Dictionnary `(key value)` where key is the name of the tab, and the value is a boolean that indicates wether this tab is loaded or not.
Next in the condition we have 2 clauses:
`*ngIf`: load the component if it's selected ond **NOT** loaded before
but the second clause in the `*ngIf` condition will leave the component visible once it's loaded, so we need to hide it using the `[class.is-hidden]` class binding

**component.ts**

```
  tabs : { [name: string] : boolean } = {"layers": false, "other-tab":false};
  currentTab : string |undefined = undefined;

  selectTab(name:string) {
  this.tabs[name] = true;
  this.currentTab = name;
}
}
```

**component.html**

```html
<tabs>
   <tab (click)="selectTab('layers')">
     <app-layers  
           *ngIf="currentTab === 'layers' || tabs['layers']"
           [class.is-hidden]="currentTab!== 'layers'">
     </app-layers>
   </tab>
   <tab click)="selectTab('other-tab')">
     <app-other-tab   
        *ngIf="currentTab=== 'other-tab' || tabs['other-tab']"
         [class.is-hidden]="currentTab!== 'other-tab'">
     </app-other-tab>
   </tab>
</tabs>
```

**component.css**

```css
.is-hidden {
      display: none;
 }
```

As you can see, I kept navigating between the tabs but this will load the component only one time and only when the user clicks the tab.

[image]

**[Demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hdkcnu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)** -used li instead of tabs for simplicity-

Comment: Yes, I is as solution, but all my components will be loaded with server requests. I need to send request only when user first time activates a components, the second time dont

Comment: Maybe to use statement inside server that knows was it first time or second, then return cached data

Comment: I am not sure I understood, can you edit the question to describe your issues please

Comment: what do you mean by user activating a compoennts? selecting a tab? you have some login in ngOnInit?

Comment: Yes, I mean activaton of life circel of component, *ngIf initializes the component all time

Comment: using this solution; if you have multiple tabs, they'll all fire the component lifecycle once (ngInit.... ngDestroy..etc) only once,  only one will be visible at a time. isn't that what you want ?

Comment: No, anyway all component will be loaded, despite user did not click tab

Comment: Ok I'll try something else

Comment: I added explanation in the answer

Comment: Thnak you, but why it does not work for swith? I use this: `<app-layers
      *ngSwitchCase="menuItemTypes.Layers || menuState[menuItemTypes.Layers]"
      [class.is-hidden]="currentMenuItem !== menuItemTypes.Layers"
    ></app-layers>`

Comment: Because *ngSwichCase is a structural directive.. it translates to *ngIf

Comment: So, I can use only ngIf?

Comment: No of course, there are other solutions with template caching but you'll struggle a little managing the whole dynamic construction and caching of the component your self. This is much simpler

Comment: Thank you a lot! The last stuped questiom, why `*ngIf` calls `ngOnIinit`, but with condition `||` not calls? Because both can be true like: `true || true` as result true